# Does GWT deferred binding return singletons of the same type within the scope of a single EntryPoint?

Tags: gwt

Let's say I have a number of GWT modules which are used as libraries, and one module with an entry point which inherits all of the library modules.

Each of the submodules needs to access a single instance of `SomeClass`.

If I call `GWT.create(SomeClass.class)` in modules A & B, do I get the same instance? If so, is this guaranteed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. `GWT.create(SomeClass.class)` compiles to `new SomeClass()`, unless there is a rebind rule of some kind - a `replace-with` or a `generate-with` rule will cause this to instead invoke the default constructor of whatever type is selected by those rules.

This means that `GWT.create` is not a suitable way to provide access to a singleton instance. Instead, consider some DI tool like Gin, or manual DI by always passing around the same instance. It is also possible to use the `static` keyword to keep a single instance where all code compiled into the same app can reference it.

Comment: To hell with the [singleton pattern](http://mike-bland.com/2012/08/16/oop-revisited.html#oop-anti-static)! (the `static` in Colin's answer) DI is the way to go, no matter how you do it (manual, GIN, etc.).